# Views Search API with Search API database, sort handler

Tags: 7, search, views

I need to have a views handler for Views Search API that will allows empty (i.e. NULL) values in fields to be sorted last.
For the simple views there is a solution: [Views Sort Null Field](https://drupal.org/project/views_sort_null_field) but I'm totally lost,  How to implement the same functionality for Views Search API?

More specifically - Views Search API provide only `$query->sort()` method that not allow you to add sort formula like `$this->query->add_orderby(NULL, "ISNULL($this->table_alias.$this->real_field)", $this->options['order'], $alias)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using [Search API Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db) as a backend for the [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) you can solve the problem by using hook_search_api_db_query_alter hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_db_query_alter().
 *
 * Preprocesses a search's database query before it is executed.
 *
 * @param SelectQueryInterface $db_query
 *   The database query to be executed for the search. Will have "item_id" and
 *   "score" columns in its result.
 * @param SearchApiQueryInterface $query
 *   The search query that is being executed.
 *
 * @see SearchApiDbService::preQuery()
 */
function custom_module_search_api_db_query_alter(SelectQueryInterface &$db_query, SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
  $db_query->orderby('ISNULL(field_field_name)', 'ASC');
}
```

This solved it and moved items with NULL values to bottom of the view. Cheers!